# How to submit a form in thymeleaf and spring boot with some client side validation of javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How to submit a form in thymeleaf and spring boot with some client side validation in javascript ,if validation fail form doest not get submitted else request goes to controller?

In below code ,how can i check if first number is greater than secondnumber 
in javascript then only form got submitted to Controller else validation error occur and form doesnot get submitted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Calculation </title>
    </head>
<body>
<h1>Subtraction</h1>
  <form action="#" id="myform" th:action="@{/result}" th:object="${subtraction}" method="POST">
   <table>
   <tr>
   
       <td/>First Number :</td>
    <td>
   <input type="text" id="firstno" th:field="*{firstnumber}" />     
   </td>    
  </tr>
   
   <tr><td>Second Number :</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" id="secondno" th:field="*{secondnumber}" />   
     </td>
     </tr>     
      <tr></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="2">
               <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
               <input type="reset" th:value="Reset"/>
             </td>
         </tr>
     
</table>  
 </form>
 
 
 <script th:inline="javascript">

   var a=/*[[${subtraction.firstnumber}]]*/;
 var b=/*[[${subtraction.secondnumber}]]*/;

function isValid(form){
  if(a>b)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

 $('#myform').submit(function(e){                                   
                    e.preventDefault();
                   if( isValid($(this))){                           
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                         url: /*[[ @{'/result'} ]]*/,
                          data:  $form.serialize(),
                          success: function(returnedData){
                              console.log(returnedData);                      
                            },    

                            error: function(xhr, exception) {

                                }
                    }); 
                   }
                   else{
                       alert("Validation failed");
                   }
                });
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Tried but not understand how it will

Comment: Do you mind adding what you have so far, so that we can guide you through it?

Comment: use th: action. In jquery function in submit or on signing up button click, prevent the default submission and get the action attribute. then validate it, if not just return or if ok, call ajax function with form data stringified and action attribute as url with type application/json. That's it

Comment: Added the code ,please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of retries, i found the solution myself

```js
 <script th:inline="javascript">
 
 

 
 $('#myform').submit(function(e){  
 
 var  a=parseInt($('#firstno').val(),10);
 console.log(a);
 var  b=parseInt($('#secondno').val(),10);
 console.log(b);
                   if(a>b){                           
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                         url: "/result.html",
                          data: $('#myform').serialize(),
                          success: function(returnedData){
                           console.log("Success"); 
                           alert("success")
                            },    

                            error: function(xhr, exception) {
                             console.log(exception);
                                }
                    }); 
                   }
                   else{
                       alert("Validation failed");
                       e.preventDefault(); 
                   }
                                     
                });
     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript/ajax for this. like below

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

function isValid(form){
  if(condition)
    return true;
  else
    return false;

}
 $('#myform ').submit(function(e){                                   
                    e.preventDefault();
                   if( isValid($(this))){                           
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                         url: /*[[ @{'/url'} ]]*/,
                          data:  $form.serialize(),
                          success: function(returnedData){
                              console.log(returnedData);                      
                            },    

                            error: function(xhr, exception) {

                                }
                    }); 
                   }
                   else{
                       alert("Validation failed");
                   }
                });
</script>
```

Comment: Please check my revised question

Comment: It's a very basic problem. Get Your input value by id and compare them inside your `isValid()` function and return true/false according to your result.